# Importing tkinter button from separate module

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

We have a functioning program that uses `Tkinter` as its GUI. Everything works fine however different branches of the code are now using different hardware which realistically need different buttons. Hence we'd like to have the main GUI import modules representing the buttons depending on what hardware is being used.

I've cut out some of the code below, I'm interested in removing the `makemenu()` function to a separate module, hence when it is called in the Application `__init__` (`self.makemenu(master)`) I would like to make that a reference to a separate module. I've tried doing this and am having trouble. Is this even possible?

I'm a little confused on the parent structure, what needs to be passed to my button module, etc.? I know this is a poorly constructed question but if anyone is able to advise if this is possible and put my on the right track that would be great. For example if someone could show how to modify [this](http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/#import) code to have the buttons defined in a separate module I could figure out how to do the same in my module.

```
# Import necessary libraries
import sys

import os

import Tkinter as tk



class Application(tk.Frame):

    ##################################################################
    ## Final functions are designed to initialize the GUI and
    ## connect various mouse movements to useful functions.
    ##################################################################

    def definevars(self):
        '''Original definition of all of the key variables that
        we need to keep track of while running the GUI

        '''    
        self.disable = True
        self.savimgstatus = 'off'
        self.mode = 'Standby'
        self.status = 'Not Ready'




    def makemenu(self,master):
        ''' Function to create the main menu bar across
        the top of the GUI.

        '''

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(master)


        ## Motor Submenu
        motormenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=1)
        motormenu.add_command(label='ALT',state='disabled')
        motormenu.add_command(label='error check',
                command=lambda: self.geterror('alt'))
        motormenu.add_separator()
        motormenu.add_command(label='AZ',state='disabled')
        motormenu.add_command(label='error check',
                command=lambda: self.geterror('az'))
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Tracker Motors',menu=motormenu)


        ## Set the big menu as the main menu bar.
        master.config(menu=self.menubar)





    def __init__(self,tcpconn,DOME,TRACKERSTAGE, master=None):
        '''Main function to initialize the GUI.  Will scale
        the size of the GUI to fit any size screen... to a
        point.  It will not allow it to be smaller than 
        600x800.

        '''


        self.buf = 1024

        ## Check resolution of screen.  Make GUI 2/3rds of size 
        ## unless that means under 600x800.
        fh = round(master.winfo_screenheight()*2./3.)
        fw = round(master.winfo_screenwidth()*2./3.)
        if fh < 600: fh = 600
        if fw < 800: fw = 800
        print 'GUI resolution set to {0} x {1}'.format(fw,fh)
        self.fw = fw
        self.fh = fh
        self.imwidth = int(0.45*self.fw)
        self.imheight = int(0.45*self.fh)
        self.imcentx = self.imwidth/2
        self.imcenty = self.imheight/2this

        ## Initialize Frame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, height=fh,width=fw)
        self.grid()
        self.grid_propagate(0)

        ## Initialize Various variables.
        self.definevars()

        ## Create buttons, etc.
        self.createWidgets()
        self.makemenu(master)
        self.disableall()

        ## Main Loop function
        self.checkoutput()

###################################################################


# Initialize GUI window.

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('Hardware') # window title

app = Application(master=root)

app.mainloop() # go into the main program loop

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move `makemenu` to a separate module, that should be pretty simple. However, you'll need to change a few things.

Since `makemenu` no longer has a reference to `self` (or has a different reference, if you implement it as a separate class), you need to replace calls like `command=lambda: self.geterror('alt'))` to be `command=lambda: master.geterror('alt'))`.

The other thing I recommend is to remove the call to add the menu to the root. I believe that modules shouldn't have side effects like this -- the function should make a menu and return it, and let the caller decide how to use it, ie:

```
self.menubar=makemenu(master)
master.configure(menu=self.menubar)
```

Roughly speaking, this is a variation of the MVC (model/view/controller) architectural pattern where the `Application` instance is your controller (and also part of the view unless you make modules of all your UI code). The menu is part of the view, and forwards UI functions to the controller for execution.

Your application then looks something like this:

```
from makemenu import makemenu

class Application(...):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.menubar = makemenu(master)
        master.config(menu=self.menubar)
        ...
```